# Pass data through Ajax get a json file

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on some code that would have a user enter a zip code in a field, if it passes client side validation when the user clicks send I want the script to send the zip code to an address and the backend developer has set it up so that it will return a json file with either valid or invalid.

The problem is that all I get back right now is, undefined.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or give some advice or trouble shooting. I'm not really sure how to use console.log and that would probably help me. Thanks.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("postalcode", function(postalcode, element) {
return this.optional(element) || postalcode.match(/(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|   (^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXYabceghjklmnpstvxy]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} ?\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1})$/);
}, "Zip code not valid. Please try again.");

var myForm = $('#zipform');

myForm.validate({
  errorClass: "errormessage, intro-highlighted",
  onkeyup: false,
  highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass('intro-highlighted');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).removeClass('intro-highlighted');
    },

  errorClass: 'error',
  validClass: 'valid',
  rules: {
    zipcode: { required: true, postalcode: true }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element)
  {
    // Set positioning based on the elements position in the form
    var elem = $(element),
      corners = ['left center', 'right center'],
      flipIt = elem.parents('span.right').length > 0;

    // Check we have a valid error message
    if(!error.is(':empty')) {
      // Apply the tooltip only if it isn't valid
      elem.filter(':not(.valid)').qtip({
        overwrite: false,
        content: error,
        position: {
          my: 'top left',
          at: 'top left',
          target: $('#zipcode'),
          adjust: {
            y: -30
          }
        },

        show: {
          event: false,
          ready: true
        },
        hide: false,
      })

      // If we have a tooltip on this element already, just update its content
      .qtip('option', 'content.text', error);
    }

    // If the error is empty, remove the qTip
    else { elem.qtip('destroy'); }
  },
  success: $.noop, // Odd workaround for errorPlacement not firing!
})

$.ajax({
    url: "http://address/icantshow/json/checkZip.action?zipCode=" + zipcode + "?jsoncallback=?",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    /*data: {
        zipcode:$('#zipcode').val(),
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
      },*/
    success: function(json) {
      console.log(typeof data);
      //console.log(jsondata);
       //$('.bar').css({display:'none'});
       //$('.loader').append(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
 })
```

Comment: `async: false` in a jsonp request doesn't make any sense, and is ignored by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //REPLACE
url: "http://address/icantshow/json/checkZip.action?zipCode=" + zipcode + "?jsoncallback=?",
//BY
    url: "http://address/icantshow/json/checkZip.action?zipCode=" + zipcode + "&jsoncallback=?",

//IN
success: function(json) {
      console.log(typeof data);
    },

//SHOULD BE
success: function(json) {
      console.log(json);
    },
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Both suggestions in this response suggest fixes that need to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections but it is still returning undefined. Any other ideas.